# Blender Octane - Editing the scene programmatically slows down terribly the rendering

Tags: python, rendering, scripting, compositing-nodes, octane-render-engine

I have this basic scene where an artist set up the Octane shader and the compositing network in order to render some sample images to test materials.
I created a script that programmatically does what follows:

- loads the scene
- accesses the shading network
- visits the textures nodes to replace the textures
- visits the displacement node and change the height value
- accesses the compositing network
- visits the file output node and changes the output format to .png, changes
  the output location and the name for the inputs
- starts the rendering process
- Saving the result of the operation in a file on the disc

The rendering executed on the scene opened and modified by the scripts is super slow, whereas if I do the same operations manually and then hit F12 the layers of the scene are rendered in a handful of minutes (6 layers rendered at 4k x 4k pictures)

Here below comes the function that runs the show.
The argument "assetsToRender" is a dictionary containing all the information necessary to setup the "mother-scene".

```
def processingScene(assetsToRender):

# basic data

REPOSITORY = "C:/wkspaces/assetdb"

SCENES_DIRECTORY = "/".join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)).split("\\")[:-2])

SCENE_MAPPING = {
    "Outdoor_Horizontal"    : os.path.normpath(os.path.join(SCENES_DIRECTORY, "Outdoor_Floor_Render_v01.blend")),
    "Outdoor_Vertical"      : os.path.normpath(os.path.join(SCENES_DIRECTORY, "Outdoor_Wall_Render_v01.blend")),
    "Indoor_Horizontal"     : os.path.normpath(os.path.join(SCENES_DIRECTORY, "Indoor_Floor_Render_v01.blend")),
    # "Indoor_Vertical"       : os.path.normpath(os.path.join(SCENES_DIRECTORY, "Indoor_Wall_Render_v01.blend")),
    "Fabric"                : os.path.normpath(os.path.join(SCENES_DIRECTORY, "Fabric_Render_v01.blend"))
}



for renderType, assets in assetsToRender.items():

    RESULT_LOG = dict(
        successful  = [],
        failed      = []
    )

    # LOADING SCENE
    loadedScene = bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile(filepath=SCENE_MAPPING[renderType])

    # process each asset of a given render type
    for asset in assets:

        assetProcessingStatus = {}

        startTime = time.time()

        try:
            assetName = asset["fields"]["Internal Source Name"]

            # get material
            octaneMaterial = bpy.data.materials["Surface"]

            materialNodesList = octaneMaterial.node_tree.nodes

            # collecting maps
            maps = dict(
                albedo      = None,
                roughness   = None,
                height      = None
            )
            for mapType in maps.keys():
                assetDirectory = os.path.join(REPOSITORY, asset["fields"]["File Path"])
                mapPath = os.path.join(assetDirectory, "02_Output")
                mapPath = os.path.join(mapPath, "{0}_{1}.png".format(assetName, mapType)).lower()
                mapPath = os.path.normpath(mapPath)

                # if not os.path.exists(mapPath):
                #     # figure out how to log errors
                #     continue

                materialNodesList[mapType].image = bpy.data.images.load(mapPath)

            # SET HEIGHT VALUE:
            height_from_airtable = "0,11.558" #need to fetch the value from airtbale record
            min, max = height_from_airtable.split(",")
            min = float(min)
            max = float(max)
            heightValueNode = materialNodesList["Texture displacement"]
            heightValueNode.inputs.get("Height").default_value = max-min

            # DEFINE RENDERING
            thumbnailDirectory = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(assetDirectory, "03_Render"))
            if not os.path.isdir(thumbnailDirectory):
                os.mkdir(thumbnailDirectory)

            tree = bpy.context.scene.node_tree

            fileOutputNode = tree.nodes["File Output"]
            fileOutputNode.base_path = thumbnailDirectory
            fileOutputNode.format.file_format = "PNG"
            for slot in fileOutputNode.file_slots:
               slot.path = "{0}_{1}".format(assetName, slot.path)


            # START RENDERING
            bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)

            stopTime = time.time()

            # LOG RESULT
            assetProcessingStatus[assetName] = "successful thumbnail rendering in {}".format(stopTime - startTime)
            RESULT_LOG["successful"].append(assetProcessingStatus)

        except Exception as e:
            assetProcessingStatus[assetName] = "FAILED - {0} - {1}".format(type(e), str(e))
            RESULT_LOG["failed"].append(assetProcessingStatus)


    return RESULT_LOG
```

Any clues where I am doing things wrong? Thanks in advance for any tip

Comment: Use (try:) may slow down you code. Try not put the bpy.ops.render.render() inside the (try:)

Comment: Thank you @X Y. That is a great tip, I will definitively need to improve the entire code since it is suppose to create and render hundred of scenes and your suggestion is very precious. 
Although I figured out where the problem was: it actually was the insanely high value for the "Texture displacement" node... pretty much a boo boo. 
Compare to the value hardcoded in the mother scene it was out of a factor of 300